# Embedded AMQP Java Broker

Tags: java, rabbitmq, automated-tests, integration-testing, amqp

I am trying to create integration test for a Scala / Java application that connects to a RabbitMQ broker. To achieve this I would like an embedded broker that speaks AMQP that I start and stop before each test. Originally I tried to introduce ActiveMQ as an embedded broker with AMQP however the application uses RabbitMQ so only speaks AMQP version 0.9.3 whereas ActiveMQ requires AMQP version 1.0.

Is there another embedded broker I can use in place of ActiveMQ?

Comment: RabbitMQ implements AMQP 0.8; 0.9.1 and AMQP 1.0. If you are using a mac, it's quite easy to start/stop rabbitmq for your tests. This is for PHP but might help you in your use case http://videlalvaro.github.io/2013/04/using-rabbitmq-in-unit-tests.html

Comment: Hi @old_sound, thanks for looking into it. Ideally I would like to avoid requiring rabbitmq on the box to test, our tests run on a CI server that we can't install RabbitMQ easily.

Comment: Does that CI server has Erlang installed at least? If yes, you can just download the rabbit tarball, uncompress it, and start/stop it for the tests

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A completely in-memory solution. Replace the `spring.*` properties as required.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
  <artifactId>qpid-broker</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
public class EmbeddedBroker {
  public void start() {
    Broker broker = new Broker();
    BrokerOptions brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions();
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.amqp_port", environment.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.port"));
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.broker.defaultPreferenceStoreAttributes", "{\"type\": \"Noop\"}");
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.vhost", environment.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host"));
    brokerOptions.setConfigurationStoreType("Memory");
    brokerOptions.setStartupLoggedToSystemOut(false);
    broker.startup(brokerOptions);
  }
}
```

Add `initial-config.json` as a resource:

```
{
  "name": "Embedded Test Broker",
  "modelVersion": "6.1",
  "authenticationproviders" : [{
    "name": "password",
    "type": "Plain",
    "secureOnlyMechanisms": [],
    "users": [{"name": "guest", "password": "guest", "type": "managed"}]
  }],
  "ports": [{
    "name": "AMQP",
    "port": "${qpid.amqp_port}",
    "authenticationProvider": "password",
    "protocols": [ "AMQP_0_9_1" ],
    "transports": [ "TCP" ],
    "virtualhostaliases": [{
      "name": "${qpid.vhost}",
      "type": "nameAlias"
    }]
  }],
  "virtualhostnodes" : [{
    "name": "${qpid.vhost}",
    "type": "Memory",
    "virtualHostInitialConfiguration": "{ \"type\": \"Memory\" }"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Be aware that if your application connects to RabbitMQ in prod, you might discover inconsistencies if you bind to Apache QPid for integration tests. RabbitMQ has extended AMQP to provide additional functionality that your application might be relying on (eg. TTLs, DLE/Qs, routing, ...). More info https://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html

Comment: QPid has most of that too, just with different names.

Comment: I can't use it because they hard code the logger class. Such a pity... org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts huh? It uses slf4j - there's no hard-coding anywhere. You can configure it to use Logback instead if for some reason you need direct access to the logger implementations.

Comment: @OrangeDog, then what do you call this in `Broker.startup()`?

    `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);`

Comment: @Timi oh yeah. The whole structure has been rewritten for 7.x though, so that may have been fixed.

Comment: @OrangeDog, thanks for pointing that out! Can you point me to some embedded examples using 7.x? The whole API seems to be changed and I found hardly any examples of how to use it. [This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/qpid/How+to+embed+Qpid+Broker-J) is all I could find, but I can't get it to work with a password file.

Comment: @Timi sorry, I haven't looked at this for a while. I suggest chatting to the devs on IRC. I know they took a lot of my feedback while I was coming up with this answer in the first place. It should be a bit simpler now.

Answer (score 13):

I've developed a wrapper around the process of downloading, extracting, starting and managing RabbitMQ so it can work like an embedded service controlled by any JVM project.

Check it out: https://github.com/AlejandroRivera/embedded-rabbitmq

It's as simple as:

```
EmbeddedRabbitMqConfig config = new EmbeddedRabbitMqConfig.Builder()
    .version(PredefinedVersion.V3_5_7)
    .build();
EmbeddedRabbitMq rabbitMq = new EmbeddedRabbitMq(config);
rabbitMq.start();
...
rabbitMq.stop();
```

Works on Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: Works great but ERL need to be pre installed is a problem for me.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the solution proposed by OrangeDog adapted to Qpid Broker 7.x, inspired from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/qpid/How+to+embed+Qpid+Broker-J):

Add qpid 7.x as test dependecies. In 7.x these have been separated in core + plugins, depending on what you need. For RabbitMQ AMQP version you'll need `qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol` and for running in-memory (sufficient for integration tests) use `qpid-broker-plugins-memory-store`.

`pom.xml`:

```
...
<properties>
    ...
    <qpid-broker.version>7.0.2</qpid-broker.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-broker-core</artifactId>
        <version>${qpid-broker.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>${qpid-broker.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-broker-plugins-memory-store</artifactId>
        <version>${qpid-broker.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependecies>
...
```

Add broker configuration with hard-coded user/password and default in-memory virtual host mapped to default port (5672):

`qpid-config.json`:

```
{
  "name": "EmbeddedBroker",
  "modelVersion": "7.0",
  "authenticationproviders": [
    {
      "name": "password",
      "type": "Plain",
      "secureOnlyMechanisms": [],
      "users": [{"name": "guest", "password": "guest", "type": "managed"}]
    }
  ],
  "ports": [
    {
      "name": "AMQP",
      "port": "${qpid.amqp_port}",
      "authenticationProvider": "password",
      "virtualhostaliases": [
        {
          "name": "defaultAlias",
          "type": "defaultAlias"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "virtualhostnodes": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "defaultVirtualHostNode": "true",
      "type": "Memory",
      "virtualHostInitialConfiguration": "{\"type\": \"Memory\" }"
    }
  ]
}
```

Define junit `ExternalResource` and declare as `ClassRule` (or start and close your embedded broker in your IT `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods):

`EmbeddedAMQPBroker.java`:

```
public class EmbeddedAMQPBroker extends ExternalResource {

    private final SystemLauncher broker = new SystemLauncher();

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        startQpidBroker();
        //createExchange();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        broker.shutdown();
    }

    private void startQpidBroker() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("type", "Memory");
        attributes.put("initialConfigurationLocation", findResourcePath("qpid-config.json"));
        broker.startup(attributes);
    }

    private String findResourcePath(final String fileName) {
        return EmbeddedAMQPBroker.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toExternalForm();
    }
}
```

Integration test:

```
public class MessagingIT{
    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedAMQPBroker embeddedAMQPBroker = new EmbeddedAMQPBroker();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any embedded RabbitMQ servers so I think you have a couple options to workaround this:

1. Your RabbitMQ server does not need to exist on your CI server, you can bring up a new server that is your CI rabbitmq server. If you can't bring one up yourself you could look into [CloudAMQP](http://www.cloudamqp.com/). The free tier today offers: 1M messages per month, 20 concurrent connections, 100 queues, 10,000 queued messages. Could be enough for your CI process.
2. If your testing is only being done unit tests for RabbitMQ you could mock out your RabbitMQ message  production. This is what we do in some of our unit tests. We just check that a certain operation make the method call to produce a specific message, but we mock this out so we don't actually publish a message. Then we test each of the consumers by explicitly calling the consumer methods with a specific message we created.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Apache QPid Java broker](https://qpid.apache.org/components/java-broker/index.html). This can be used as embedded broker.

Setup in Scala is described in another SO question - [Example of standalone Apache Qpid (amqp) Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176043/example-of-standalone-apache-qpid-amqp-junit-test/26765280)