# Spring, Junit, and Qpid - AMQSession.Dispatch won't stop so the test will not end

Tags: java, junit, spring-integration, spring-jms, qpid

I'm running a few integration tests with Qpid (qpid setup based on [the answer to this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176043/example-of-standalone-apache-qpid-amqp-junit-test). The application is a Spring Integration flow, receives an incoming message and processes. The test will receive the messages, process, and then check assertions on the outcome of the process.

I managed to start the java broker in the `@Before` method of the test, and the test will run correctly, but when the test finishes, the broker shuts down on `@After`, and then (on the client side I think, but I'm not sure), instead of wrapping up, new instances of `org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession.Dispatcher` are created, and they end up in an endless loop instead of closing.

`[2016-05-20 17:29:28,457][DEBUG][org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-2][org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession.Dispatcher] - Dispatcher-2-Conn-2 created
[2016-05-20 17:29:28,457][DEBUG][Dispatcher-2-Conn-2][org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession.Dispatcher] - Dispatcher-2-Conn-2 started`

Then Dispatcher-2-Conn-2 will run forever in a loop without ending. Spring is using a `org.apache.qpid.client.PooledConnectionFactory` as argument for a spring JmsTemplate for sending the messages.

So my questions are:

- Anybody have any experience with qpid java broker + junit? (beyond the link below) to highlight anything that would be glaringly obvious that I'm missing from the setup/teardown.
- I think the rebel threads are on the client side rather than the broker. How would one get hold of all sessions/connections/etc created by Spring to properly terminate them?
- Would killing the vm stop a jenkins build that has this test? :D

(The tests used to run correctly with ActiveMQ, and with **far** less configuration and setup, but we've been told to move away from ActiveMQ so here we are).

Comment: You need to show all of your test configuration in order for anybody to help.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your response. I understand it's  pretty difficult to guess anything with this information, but I can't post the actual code without breaking my NDA. I'll try to reproduce it at home and post that configuration instead.